# How can I get OpenGL headers without installing dev package?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, header, centos

The package (mesa-libGL) to install from `yum` has many dependencies and is rather large (35MB reported by yum)

I want to do some small amounts of code review and editing on my CentOS server. This is a server I primarily SSH into and runs no window manager, so all the X dependencies, etc. are useless.

But I would like to have my editor (vim with YouCompleteMe plugin for the libclang integration) not give me blocking errors for missing GL headers.

Is there a better solution than manually copying over headers from another linux setup? Maybe there is some repository somewhere that has the raw header files I can just curl to my server.

Comment: I would install the development packages using `yum` (or whatever package manager you are using). Even if all the dependencies take a few hundreds megabytes, this is not a big deal on today's VPS.... You probably have more than 10Gbytes total.

Comment: What good are headers without the library to link to?

Comment: @NicolBolas For my editor. I won't be linking them. I'm only running libclang analysis on them. (The rest of the file's warnings/errors won't get processed if the analysis fails to find a header) -- as for why this is important, it's when I have the ability to SSH to my Linux server but don't have my macbook on me (to run Xcode), to work on an Xcode project by editing the C++ and Obj-C source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Mesa sources](ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/). Take needed files in `include` folder and delete other stuff. Put these files in system folder or just point your editor to them.